# FB.ui dialog not displayed on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, ipad, mobile, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB.ui to trigger a requests dialog. The dialog loads properly on non-mobile devices. However, it fails to load on mobile devices like iPad. What appears is something like a popup/iframe with a `loading-gif`.

```
 FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests', 
            message: 'Hello People',
            title: 'A friendly hello',
            data: 'some-data',
            display: 'touch',
            access_token: my_access_token,
        }, callback);
```

I have tried with `display: 'iframe'`, `display:'popup'`, `display: 'wap'` and `display: 'page'`. But nothing works. How can I get it working on mobile devices? Thank you.

Comment: I have this same exact problem. Anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a URL redirect for my mobile devices like here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#web

> To display a mobile-friendly Feed
>   Dialog, redirect the user to the
>   following URL:
>
> http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
>       client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&display=touch

I assume it works similarly for the apprequests method you are using.

Comment: I have tried this solution on iPad and still couldn't get it working with apprequests. I will try one more time when I have time and mention the result here. Thanks for the response.

Comment: It may not work in the same way as the feed dialog but I thought it was worth trying. Good luck and maybe someone with some more experience can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

My original response was deleted because the mod thought I was creating a new question. I was in fact responding to

> I have tried this solution on iPad and still couldn't get it working with apprequests. I will try one more time when I have time and mention the result here. Thanks for the response. > – dheerosaur Jul 18 at 10:52

I have found the solution for people still having issues specifically with iPad, namely @dheerosaur and documented it here:

http://deansofer.com/posts/view/9/Facebook-UI-Modals-on-iPads-are-Borked

The trick is to supply this piece of CSS:

```
#fb_dialog_ipad_overlay {
    width: 600px !important;
}
```

I also submitted a bug ticket to FB to look into it.

Comment: It's also possible the mod thought you were plugging your blog instead of providing a relevant answer. I've inoculated your answer against this, I hope, by adding the solution to your answer instead of expecting people to click through to your blog. People are much more likely to use the answer if it is self-contained in the SO site.